Weaviate fetch failed on Embedded TypeScript
On the local embedded version of Weaviate, I keep getting a fetch failed error:
(node:56242) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at async file:///Users/tejas1/Documents/Code/_Constella/desktop-electron-app/node_modules/graphql-request/src/index.ts:191:12
    at async makeRequest (file:///Users/tejas1/Documents/Code/_Constella/desktop-electron-app/node_modules/graphql-request/src/index.ts:408:20)
    at async getWeaviateClient (/Users/tejas1/Documents/Code/_Constella/desktop-electron-app/src/db/weaviate.js:62:12)

My code is:
// connects to client -> creates collection -> adds data -> searches
export const testWeaviateClient = async () => {
  const client = await clientPromise;
  await client.embedded.start();

  try {
    const className = 'NodeNew';
    const classObj = {
      class: className,
      properties: [
        {
          name: 'title',
          dataType: ['text'],
        },
        {
          name: 'content',
          dataType: ['text'],
        },
      ],
      vectorizer: 'none',
    };
    await client.schema.classCreator().withClass(classObj).do();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('COLLECTION ALREADY EXISTS');
  }

  let result = await client.data
    .creator()
    .withClassName('NodeNew')
    .withProperties({
      title: 'napolean bonaparte',
      content: 'an emperor of France',
    })
    .withVector(Array(1536).fill(0.12345))
    .do();

  console.log('CREATED NODE');
  console.log(result);

  // wait 5 seconds to ensure local weaviate is ready
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  console.log('STARTING SEARCH');

  result = await client.graphql
    .get()
    .withClassName('NodeNew')
    .withNearVector({
      vector: [
        -0.0125526935, -0.021168863, -0.01076519, -0.02589537, -0.0070362035,
        0.019870078, -0.010001986, -0.019120263, 0.00090044655, -0.017393013,
        0.021302758, 0.010055545, 0.02937665, -0.003816019, 0.007692291,
        0.012385325, 0.032750815, 0.020847514, 0.020311933, -0.022159688,
        -0.0009924996, 0.009399457, 0.0022226637, -0.029510546, 0.014393755,
        -0.007223657, 0.018276723, -0.03639277, -0.010001986, -0.022842556,
        0.010363504, -0.020927852, -0.006929087, -0.022521207, -0.007652122,
        -0.011126708, 0.0279038, -0.01721895, 0.016482525, 0.002281243,
        -0.00169294, 0.009191919, -0.019655844, -0.022869334, -0.012412104,
        0.0031967526, -0.0033457114, -0.01483561, -0.03173321, 0.004746592,
        0.010095714, 0.007973471, -0.032134898, -0.023739655, -0.008040419,
        0.018290112, -0.013637247, -0.008488968, 0.024623364, -0.039365247,
        -0.0032586793, 0.0009606995, -0.029510546, 0.0063265576, -0.019602288,
        0.003081268, 0.013463182, -0.006601043, 0.019910246, -0.01542475,
        0.0367409, -0.01193008, 0.012961075, -0.015625594, 0.0062462203,
        -0.0058646183, -0.0059248717, 0.01889264, 0.008127451, 0.0037155973,
        0.037142586, -0.025373178, -0.005503101, 0.014982895, 0.035053816,
        -0.012432188, -0.017285896, 0.022936283, 0.0024620018, 0.016937768,
        -0.0062127467, 0.02154377, 0.0066378643, 0.029698, 0.0013071538,
        0.0043850746, -0.008040419, 0.024797428, -0.012452273, -0.025132166,
        -0.0031900578, 0.0000019433794, -0.002378317, -0.008629559, 0.0126732,
        -0.0022494427, 0.0009623732, 0.0035582704, 0.017312676, -0.024569806,
        -0.008890655, 0.023056788, 0.014902558, -0.047104403, -0.009011161,
        -0.030447815, 0.017982153, -0.0042009684, -0.00654079, 0.00069249026,
        0.011936775, 0.023378137, 0.025105387, -0.009245478, 0.030929837,
        0.00394322, 0.02123581, -0.0042545265, 0.0022578111, -0.017259117,
        0.047157962, -0.00022029977, 0.03497348, -0.00072094303, -0.023605758,
        0.036499888, -0.015384582, 0.011099929, -0.0139519, -0.03408977,
        0.013155223, 0.030501373, -0.026698742, 0.004311432, -0.010236303,
        0.011361024, 0.023793213, -0.00014874942, 0.0020352101, 0.0026829292,
        0.00989487, 0.0074780583, 0.02734144, 0.003826061, 0.011722542,
        0.00712993, -0.013992069, 0.0009406152, 0.010785274, -0.012325072,
        0.01692438, 0.010617905, 0.016750315, -0.0070295087, 0.017687583,
        0.038320865, 0.020485997, 0.005054551, -0.018812304, 0.0007201062,
        0.0015381235, 0.0349467, 0.014728494, 0.050773136, -0.017901815,
        0.0027716348, 0.0064704954, 0.026671965, -0.015063233, -0.013536825,
        0.016696757, 0.008127451, 0.026966535, 0.029912233, -0.0031431946,
        0.015156959, 0.012412104, -0.047907773, 0.022012403, -0.027006702,
        -0.0069491714, 0.010718327, 0.011976943, -0.008127451, -0.65212417,
        0.00024289463, 0.0051214993, -0.013007938, 0.022373922, 0.0337952,
        -0.0026829292, -0.0110463705, -0.013034717, -0.0012167745, 0.010062239,
        -0.0023013272, 0.024409132, -0.009118277, -0.020191427, -0.01597372,
        0.010115798, -0.030929837, -0.010932559, 0.010912475, -0.0009841312,
        0.010571042, -0.008348378, -0.009104887, 0.02711382, 0.0036553445,
        -0.018263333, -0.030876279, 0.014594599, 0.037704945, -0.030126465,
        0.014366977, 0.0055533117, 0.003487975, 0.044988856, 0.009881481,
        -0.012699978, 0.041132666, 0.01744657, 0.05417408, -0.004686339,
        0.016121006, 0.0070495927, 0.015478308, -0.020593112, 0.0012376956,
        0.027127208, -0.0051248465, 0.0005979267, 0.0063366, -0.008616169,
        0.027877023, -0.00042679158, 0.008442105, 0.00069751136, 0.023806602,
        0.029296314, -0.0047332025, 0.027877023, 0.0033005215, 0.014996285,
        -0.0061424514, 0.00451897, 0.015531867, -0.015317634, 0.044185482,
        0.010196134, 0.007504837, 0.012405409, -0.030126465, 0.03821375,
        0.0256008, -0.016710145, 0.0032804373, -0.013884953, 0.022775607,
        0.030608488, -0.023431696, -0.008502358, 0.008683117, -0.0045490963,
        -0.0030143203, -0.024074392, 0.00874337, 0.009466405, -0.0072370465,
        -0.021383096, 0.001360712, 0.020298542, 0.0040168623, 0.008201093,
        0.011106623, -0.03202778, 0.0046461704, -0.00088370964, -0.008957602,
        0.0057575023, 0.00037407028, 0.017259117, -0.0482559, -0.0049507823,
        -0.024235068, -0.0014418861, 0.004425243, 0.023244241, 0.0107919695,
        -0.017058274, 0.0183035, 0.033339955, -0.009091497, 0.000118936776,
        0.0031900578, -0.000044483608, -0.017058274, 0.001529755, -0.027984139,
        0.02740839, -0.015344413, 0.015264076, -0.01719217, 0.010463926,
        -0.0067048124, 0.014942727, -0.00026653553, 0.02677908, -0.00036570182,
        -0.043194655, -0.022855945, -0.011294077, 0.005764197, 0.004910614,
        -0.0029724778, 0.0056637754, -0.01425986, -0.000008708432, 0.01866502,
        0.031626094, 0.0050378144, 0.015451529, 0.009406152, -0.030742384,
        -0.0024318753, -0.029751558, -0.008348378, 0.0028519721, -0.008388547,
        -0.010611211, 0.0139519, -0.0006895613, -0.001230164, -0.0062462203,
        -0.013510046, 0.010617905, -0.010229609, 0.022213247, -0.00610563,
        -0.00568386, -0.0056503857, 0.02416812, -0.0076253433, 0.015183738,
        -0.005188447, -0.016080838, 0.013516741, 0.0062897364, -0.0068520973,
        0.021396484, 0.007799407, -0.01721895, -0.025266062, 0.013791226,
        -0.017205559, -0.002068684, 0.032938268, 0.014661547, 0.023552202,
        -0.005827797, -0.008442105, -0.0074914475, 0.009111582, 0.016817262,
        -0.0050244248, -0.005871313, -0.008368462, 0.040329296, 0.008683117,
        0.031518977, 0.026109602, -0.025815032, 0.011006202, -0.0034310697,
        0.019575508, -0.013831395, -0.008676422, -0.008770149, -0.019990584,
        0.008750064, 0.02851972, 0.0337952, 0.012666505, 0.021383096,
        -0.027448557, 0.0035448808, -0.016214734, 0.015197128, -0.027582452,
        -0.0138046155, -0.03899034, 0.008261346, 0.015478308, 0.017888425,
        0.0153979715, 0.010658074, -0.011581952, 0.02530623, 0.017982153,
        -0.0059449556, 0.0054294583, 0.0022879376, -0.018758746, -0.0076119537,
        -0.027689569, 0.013463182, 0.011186961, -0.0063165156, 0.028412605,
        0.011347636, 0.008709895, -0.003374164, -0.007919913, -0.025828423,
        0.0033875536, -0.013831395, -0.0035716598, 0.010450536, -0.025172336,
        0.003990083, -0.00093224674, 0.024047613, 0.008027029, -0.0029440252,
        0.023458473, 0.016643198, -0.0326437, 0.019147042, 0.01925416,
        -0.0020151257, 0.0038628823, -0.026738912, 0.0008753412, -0.025105387,
        0.0069491714, -0.02623011, 0.027033482, -0.0040737675, -0.021034967,
        0.019468391, 0.0026042655, 0.03467891, 0.016107617, -0.0057139862,
        -0.011735932, 0.017687583, 0.011628816, 0.015090012, -0.006678033,
        -0.011715848, -0.01833028, 0.008040419, -0.01921399, -0.03267048,
        -0.005914829, 0.0014435598, -0.0030662047, 0.005479669, 0.01597372,
        -0.01454104, 0.023257632, 0.019722793, 0.0344379, 0.006929087,
        -0.043248214, 0.015853215, 0.012766927, -0.007417805, -0.018316891,
        -0.01163551, -0.017352844, -0.01978974, 0.015304244, -0.00005920687,
        0.033580966, -0.0022343795, 0.0047800657, -0.007357552, 0.00033536615,
        0.00887057, -0.025654359, 0.016388796, -0.011361024, 0.00019090556,
        0.0060119033, -0.010075629, -0.0131485285, 0.01604067, -0.015531867,
        0.0035616176, -0.017259117, 0.0035415334, 0.009265562, -0.0043348637,
        -0.005867966, -0.03283115, -0.004773371, -0.018410617, -0.0095400475,
        -0.006520706, -0.00414741, 0.031197628, 0.013690805, -0.008984381,
        -0.022320364, -0.012492441, -0.005724028, 0.09806499, 0.017272506,
        -0.00007704216, 0.00858939, 0.0030126465, -0.002835235, -0.023753043,
        -0.025587412, 0.016067449, 0.0024536331, 0.004719813, -0.02908208,
        0.027743127, 0.0023414958, 0.0152908545, 0.00552988, -0.031974223,
        0.0019582203, 0.010812053, -0.01952195, -0.00006171741, -0.02241409,
        0.025252672, 0.013737668, 0.002356559, -0.03719614, 0.021637497,
        0.033580966, 0.0044453274, -0.0074378895, -0.014715104, -0.01741979,
        -0.013489962, -0.003221858, 0.0038561875, -0.013121749, -0.012974464,
        0.012619642, 0.053424265, -0.020459218, 0.011581952, 0.041962817,
        -0.00087032013, -0.0036988605, -0.0010025419, -0.020392269, 0.014902558,
        0.021409875, 0.01771436, -0.006483885, 0.036633782, -0.00028808432,
        0.011983639, 0.014326808, 0.024931323, 0.002629371, -0.01223804,
        -0.010972728, -0.011253908, 0.013831395, -0.01748674, -0.013777837,
        -0.0043449057, -0.009292341, -0.0015849868, -0.019455003, -0.031170849,
        -0.014393755, -0.03778528, -0.0028335615, -0.00785966, -0.027528895,
        -0.021008188, -0.03786562, -0.0008226199, -0.005539922, 0.011970249,
        -0.016937768, -0.0044553694, 0.015839826, -0.014929337, -0.011166876,
        0.0031448682, -0.032402687, -0.011207045, -0.009432931, 0.0034059642,
        -0.00089124124, -0.009439626, -0.012840569, 0.013610467, 0.008877265,
        0.006108978, 0.0021289368, 0.039124236, 0.0025557284, -0.004277958,
        0.02822515, 0.022373922, -0.00888396, 0.032777593, -0.021610718,
        -0.010490704, -0.0017222296, -0.011113319, -0.024569806, 0.0024703701,
        0.021155473, -0.004555791, -0.0060353354, 0.008241262, -0.03234913,
        -0.00048076818, -0.0069960346, 0.02910886, 0.013315897, -0.014728494,
        0.01454104, -0.00567047, -0.0012602905, 0.0001736456, 0.005302258,
        -0.0000424961, 0.035589397, -0.01570593, 0.0107919695, 0.0051348885,
        -0.015331023, -0.0034193539, 0.003625218, -0.010477315, 0.024583196,
        -0.0030226887, -0.011776101, -0.040115062, -0.009091497, -0.003886314,
        0.017888425, -0.03143864, -0.008629559, -0.005533227, -0.017138612,
        0.01338954, -0.02681925, -0.006688075, -0.026538068, 0.0050210776,
        0.011401193, 0.0076655117, 0.008576, -0.028171593, -0.0022025793,
        0.005911482, 0.017205559, -0.02066006, -0.0413469, -0.016910989,
        0.0097944485, 0.020807344, 0.030742384, 0.026738912, -0.011628816,
        0.03350063, 0.011146792, -0.024556417, 0.019709403, -0.00712993,
        0.012110839, -0.044694286, 0.02795736, 0.016777094, -0.0054729744,
        0.025975708, 0.0109191695, 0.009821228, 0.012485746, 0.01571932,
        0.0018661672, -0.014567819, -0.010972728, 0.0022394005, 0.01626829,
        0.0014820547, -0.0030026045, 0.004120631, -0.023699487, 0.040918436,
        0.0011640531, -0.0092856465, -0.0180491, 0.03459857, -0.013161918,
        -0.0036151758, -0.0073910262, 0.0028737301, -0.017968763, -0.016549472,
        -0.01355691, 0.0031616052, 0.0067516756, 0.0023096956, -0.0076789013,
        -0.009955123, 0.011233824, -0.0072906045, 0.016402187, 0.009727501,
        -0.0153979715, 0.020445827, -0.0042980425, -0.024556417, -0.048496913,
        -0.026886197, -0.047693543, 0.0007615301, -0.013925122, -0.010437147,
        0.01483561, -0.0050277724, -0.022266805, 0.02793058, -0.015264076,
        0.032563362, 0.00472316, 0.017526908, 0.021061746, -0.013818005,
        -0.021945456, 0.028573278, -0.0313583, 0.016469134, 0.00013180329,
        -0.000116426236, -0.0018477566, -0.03722292, -0.002868709, 0.001186648,
        -0.037463933, -0.046568822, 0.0128004, 0.015197128, 0.013054801,
        -0.017821478, -0.022320364, -0.022012403, 0.013289118, -0.0043516005,
        -0.0029808464, -0.01660303, -0.03786562, -0.024877766, -0.013356066,
        -0.006825318, 0.027582452, -0.0042545265, -0.0017063295, 0.024891155,
        -0.0049240035, -0.014500872, -0.016803874, 0.008127451, 0.022855945,
        -0.0014284966, -0.006339947, 0.01604067, 0.0026092867, 0.012057281,
        -0.008569306, 0.00007374708, 0.02766279, -0.025774864, 0.0047064233,
        -0.024676923, 0.013938512, -0.002286264, -0.011166876, -0.024074392,
        -0.018450785, -0.0049842563, 0.0035080595, 0.028305488, 0.033286396,
        -0.003054489, -0.003272069, -0.024502859, 0.021302758, -0.015558646,
        -0.006798539, 0.005667123, -0.01716539, 0.003325627, 0.00885718,
        -0.0047767186, -0.0073843314, -0.0038193662, -0.009352594, 0.0209948,
        0.041507576, -0.036526665, -0.0022661798, -0.035401944, 0.012204566,
        -0.034759246, -0.008850486, -0.0009975208, -0.00022176426, -0.008629559,
        -0.015357803, -0.01455443, -0.0059416085, -0.01687082, 0.014487483,
        -0.0008845465, -0.0010284841, 0.02708704, 0.028653616, 0.0033189321,
        -0.025373178, 0.0036620393, 0.018772135, -0.0031130682, 0.0070495927,
        -0.00006830758, -0.017674193, 0.000969068, -0.018290112, -0.005546617,
        0.0037658082, -0.00016872912, -0.024784038, -0.020860903, 0.02070023,
        0.0029138986, -0.036285654, -0.041159447, -0.022106132, -0.018651629,
        0.03435756, -0.008194398, -0.020485997, 0.01660303, 0.026270278,
        0.0079065235, 0.0015649025, -0.005807713, -0.012733453, -0.0042377897,
        -0.021891898, -0.0180491, -0.008783538, -0.017111832, 0.005493059,
        0.011501615, -0.0025657706, -0.018946199, 0.006052072, -0.0120438915,
        0.010644685, -0.005165015, 0.009881481, 0.02677908, -0.0035716598,
        0.005449543, 0.021758003, -0.0072035724, 0.010745106, -0.012130924,
        -0.0011799532, 0.0036620393, -0.0034411119, 0.013028023, 0.045095973,
        -0.021396484, -0.01895959, 0.016281681, 0.0020050837, 0.008214483,
        0.004632781, -0.030501373, -0.019709403, -0.021075137, -0.0027230978,
        -0.015183738, 0.0008828728, 0.015304244, -0.0034578487, -0.02940343,
        0.015344413, 0.00785966, -0.0026260235, -0.008529137, 0.00442859,
        0.0013900016, 0.0001500047, -0.024368962, -0.005580091, -0.017205559,
        -0.0285465, 0.0054729744, -0.0009422889, -0.0076722065, 0.02475726,
        -0.02241409, -0.016469134, -0.0064370213, 0.00018034037, 0.009044634,
        -0.0044486746, 0.000060462142, -0.014942727, 0.026658574, -0.0043181265,
        0.030046128, -0.042043157, 0.016616419, -0.007170099, 0.02040566,
        -0.008227873, 0.025975708, -0.027877023, -0.022668492, 0.0051181517,
        -0.007116541, 0.016522693, -0.0025373178, -0.0018259985, -0.015906774,
        0.013858174, -0.019843299, 0.0029942358, -0.01632185, -0.029831896,
        -0.024007445, -0.0045022327, -0.015946941, 0.030662047, 0.18091947,
        -0.016576251, 0.003936525, 0.039659817, -0.008160925, 0.021168863,
        0.026002487, -0.0043248213, -0.008488968, 0.0125526935, -0.007839575,
        0.024020836, -0.014500872, 0.008529137, 0.0011925059, -0.015652372,
        -0.00050880254, -0.0032017739, -0.006353337, -0.03438434, -0.013208781,
        -0.0023113694, -0.011608731, -0.015411361, 0.022842556, 0.0013423014,
        -0.0017356192, -0.005104762, 0.0062395255, 0.0056403438, 0.0061960095,
        -0.033018608, 0.0053591635, -0.02067345, -0.001453602, -0.013289118,
        -0.02851972, 0.028118035, 0.0052687842, 0.01338954, -0.0035314912,
        0.009673943, 0.009191919, 0.01281379, -0.013992069, 0.008134145,
        -0.004575875, 0.0015013022, -0.00028620142, 0.03550906, -0.0512016,
        0.010477315, 0.008897349, 0.03347385, -0.02471709, 0.0011297425,
        0.005851229, -0.019588897, 0.012037196, 0.010182745, 0.0065776114,
        0.030233582, -0.01309497, 0.018839084, -0.024623364, 0.0072370465,
        -0.02241409, 0.03400943, -0.00069207186, -0.014674936, -0.0031833632,
        -0.024784038, -0.02645773, -0.012793706, -0.0008506542, -0.03583041,
        -0.012325072, 0.026966535, 0.01018944, 0.013356066, -0.02474387,
        -0.014326808, -0.007658817, 0.012827179, -0.02740839, -0.015277465,
        0.021784782, -0.0015858236, -0.0018460829, 0.0004573365, -0.0057072914,
        -0.019588897, 0.0058411867, -0.002308022, -0.00066278223, 0.006460453,
        -0.00038369402, 0.018705187, -0.009078108, -0.020298542, -0.035991084,
        -0.047211517, 0.018571293, -0.0041775363, -0.008676422, -0.002138979,
        -0.007504837, -0.00078579865, 0.014621378, -0.0043850746, -0.01455443,
        -0.015906774, 0.0010176051, 0.006935782, 0.025199115, -0.0038093242,
        0.013690805, -0.022253416, 0.036874793, -0.019053316, -0.0044821487,
        0.0042377897, 0.005998514, 0.0064102425, 0.008080588, -0.028064476,
        -0.025239283, 0.0070295087, 0.023083568, -0.028653616, -0.010771885,
        -0.019280938, -0.005563354, -0.012579473, -0.005258742, 0.0012109166,
        0.015531867, -0.017339455, 0.016241511, 0.0069424766, 0.015652372,
        0.014380367, 0.006791844, -0.0023967277, 0.037945956, -0.0285465,
        0.02128937, 0.0049942983, -0.029831896, -0.023819992, -0.016281681,
        -0.0031850368, 0.0029691304, -0.0038227136, 0.023645928, -0.036473107,
        -0.02153038, -0.025279451, -0.010242999, 0.018156216, -0.025413347,
        0.0036218707, 0.005111457, -0.014487483, -0.0059784297, -0.013690805,
        -0.171279, -0.0037222921, 0.01626829, -0.010417062, -0.0007322405,
        -0.001834367, 0.008776844, -0.012867348, -0.005884703, -0.0027147292,
        0.022306973, 0.0042244, -0.049300287, -0.0157461, 0.016054058,
        0.002781677, 0.00197161, 0.007980166, -0.014366977, -0.0071834885,
        0.021048358, -0.024971493, 0.017955374, -0.007692291, 0.0043683373,
        0.018557902, 0.01570593, 0.0027063608, 0.0011791164, -0.03698191,
        -0.014875779, 0.008455494, 0.016536081, 0.009486489, -0.001415107,
        0.002960762, -0.008368462, -0.021878509, -0.022454258, 0.004686339,
        0.012392019, 0.04394447, 0.016121006, -0.0068085813, 0.014085797,
        -0.0022946324, 0.008509053, -0.0063868104, 0.022333752, -0.026591627,
        0.006497274, -0.01454104, 0.0080337245, -0.0059014396, 0.01602728,
        0.02651129, -0.010738411, 0.014567819, -0.010303251, -0.031010175,
        -0.03821375, -0.0056403438, -0.00006835988, -0.0011732584, -0.021945456,
        -0.011146792, -0.023498643, 0.021409875, -0.026712133, -0.004190926,
        0.002542339, 0.0062462203, -0.004522317, -0.02967122, 0.008334989,
        0.00029415145, -0.018544514, 0.022240026, -0.024261847, -0.021811562,
        -0.020566333, 0.0390439, -0.025466906, 0.014059017, 0.013476572,
        -0.007451279, -0.0101760505, -0.021918677, 0.004093852, -0.003772503,
        0.034304, -0.029483767, -0.025574021, -0.015893385, -0.003407638,
        0.030233582, 0.007799407, 0.00002280406, 0.021838339, -0.01633524,
        -0.006875529, -0.010229609, 0.0053256894, 0.02011109, -0.010885696,
        0.04016862, 0.028760733, 0.015183738, 0.013061496, -0.0073307734,
        0.0077324593, 0.007739154, 0.015344413, 0.03783884, -0.012124228,
        0.0145276515, -0.00086027797, 0.0006744981, 0.035375167, -0.0044620642,
        0.030903058, 0.01567915, -0.0053189946, -0.014045628, -0.018852472,
        0.0035683124, -0.09554776, -0.013791226, -0.015116791, 0.0013891648,
        -0.026377395, 0.019147042, -0.008254652, 0.040623866, -0.01656286,
        0.01948178, 0.01310836, -0.006025293, 0.005971735, -0.0051348885,
        0.019843299, 0.02007092, -0.027421778, 0.00007709446, 0.0038896615,
        0.005737418, 0.010095714, -0.0044988855, 0.011294077, -0.001899641,
        -0.01567915, 0.007216962, -0.02095463, 0.024797428, -0.0064805374,
        0.010691548, 0.01208406, -0.012867348, -0.0057775867, -0.023110347,
        -0.019588897, 0.0060821986, -0.019374665, -0.0061391043, 0.031331524,
        -0.018490955, 0.004043641, 0.0032017739, -0.003973346, -0.014982895,
        0.008696507, -0.025989097, 0.007156709, 0.013523435, -0.0041139363,
        -0.03055493, -0.02793058, -0.011106623, -0.02851972, 0.023753043,
        0.04689017, 0.0035850494, 0.009834617, 0.0096003, 0.016147785,
        0.019856688, 0.0031582578, 0.004666255, -0.00829482, 0.0395527,
        -0.01077858, -0.020512775, -0.020512775, 0.012057281, 0.027006702,
        -0.021999015, -0.009633774, 0.02878751, -0.026645185, -0.005057899,
        -0.016964547, 0.003315585, -0.02910886, -0.008107367, 0.0138046155,
        -0.023538811, -0.0028804247, -0.03491992, 0.0076789013, -0.03781206,
        0.014032238, 0.019642456, 0.021798171, -0.0074780583, -0.01602728,
        -0.011909996, -0.015183738, 0.0031063734, 0.0016686714, -0.036553446,
        -0.0018594724, 0.015906774, -0.009225393, 0.006755023, 0.0065776114,
        0.0139117325, -0.0045524435, 0.0051583205, -0.049166393, 0.018477565,
        -0.010182745, 0.0031398472, 0.022614934, 0.0048905294, 0.027234325,
        -0.005191794, 0.026966535, -0.0012477378, -0.029483767, 0.010303251,
        -0.0072370465, 0.015505088, -0.015183738, -0.009948429, 0.00054185797,
        -0.016844042, 0.0015339392, -0.008495663, 0.01105976, 0.008375158,
        0.013992069, 0.00698934, 0.0035448808, 0.01427325, 0.0080538085,
        0.005382595, -0.021677665, 0.004900572, 0.008977687, -0.034812804,
        0.005998514, 0.024984881, 0.0032687215, -0.02795736, 0.009124972,
        0.0022778956, 0.0038126716, 0.012646421, 0.0019180516, -0.0128004,
        0.013034717, -0.046033237, -0.00021506949, -0.005104762, -0.010309946,
        0.0054093744, 0.01632185, -0.005737418, 0.016937768, 0.010945949,
        -0.018129438, 0.0039532618, -0.0047432445, -0.04051675, 0.03703547,
        0.007551701, 0.0031264576, 0.00073935365, 0.012887432, 0.00020000625,
        0.003869577, -0.012961075, -0.010443841, 0.038481537, 0.0037089025,
        -0.013643941, 0.03639277, -0.040329296, -0.022293584, 0.004087157,
        0.011709153, 0.014902558, -0.006122367, 0.007852965, 0.003081268,
        0.018571293, -0.0077190697, 0.020927852, 0.021195643, -0.00010554723,
        -0.029055303, 0.006269652, 0.029885454, 0.0060554193, -0.0075583956,
        0.0008188541, 0.013041412, -0.006453758, -0.03467891, 0.005814408,
        0.015090012, 0.010383588, 0.013818005, 0.018504344, -0.025761476,
        -0.011856438, 0.0052219206, 0.021423263, 0.00829482, -0.009881481,
        -0.01326234, -0.0038093242, -0.016951159, -0.005590133, -0.0067115068,
        -0.03483958, -0.010838833, 0.01717878, 0.038053073, -0.015612204,
        -0.004231095, 0.008027029, -0.008040419, 0.025667747, -0.005677165,
        -0.016455745, -0.028010918, 0.024342183, 0.010095714, 0.014219692,
        0.016910989, -0.00083266204, 0.010182745, 0.021516992, 0.011950164,
        -0.03055493, -0.012104144, 0.004468759, -0.006969256, -0.014393755,
        -0.021342928, 0.0085626105, -0.015665762, 0.0021841687, -0.004234442,
        0.030715605, -0.017138612, 0.042712633, 0.0062462203, 0.020057531,
        0.008073892, -0.0326437, 0.01250583, 0.024342183, 0.04747931,
        -0.027020091, 0.0019414834, 0.015170349, -0.016362019, 0.02825193,
        -0.009566827, -0.039954387, -0.00697595, -0.023927107, -0.0285465,
        -0.000100316945, -0.024850987, 0.022963062, 0.002122242, 0.027877023,
        0.0012870695, -0.018182995, -0.0079266075, 0.016174564, -0.010068934,
        -0.015090012, -0.0054227635, 0.0051516257, -0.013235561, -0.0075583956,
        -0.0131485285, 0.039365247, 0.0065575275, -0.011474836, 0.0028268667,
        -0.004425243, -0.0020703576, -0.010631295, -0.011702458, -0.0038394507,
        0.0059784297, 0.032268792, 0.02244087, -0.023458473, -0.0053859423,
        -0.01925416,
      ],
    })
    .withLimit(2)
    .withFields('content title { distance }')
    .do();

  console.log('SEARCH RESULTS:');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));

  return await clientPromise;
};


Connecting to a node, creating a collection, and adding a node seems to work fine. Just the searching part seems to be giving this opaque error.
Note: I installed the library by doing npm i weaviate-ts-embedded (saw there was also the TS client separately which made it confusing)
